# Rotating column values in a table in clockwise direction

Tags: sql-server

```
I have a table like this 
   c1   c2  c3
    1   2   3
    4   5   6
    7   8   9

I need output like this......       
    c1  c2  c3
    9   1   2
    3   4   5
    6   7   8
```

I tried but i didn't get any idea 
if anyone knows the answer please add some explanation for that answer .........

Comment: Do you need this for this certain case (3x3) or a generic, magic multi-dimensional thing? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes ,i need for case  (3x3) just to rotate the column values

Comment: should c1 contain  3 6 9 or  9 3 6 ?

Comment: C1 has to contain only 9 3 6 only

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by rotating data like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try, this may be help you to solve the issue

```
DECLARE @V_MAX INT 
SELECT  @V_MAX = c3 FROM [tablec]
;WITH CTE_TEST
AS
(   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ROW_NO,*   FROM [tablec] 
)
SELECT ISNULL(T.c3,@V_MAX) C1,M.c1 C2,M.c2 C3 FROM CTE_TEST M
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM CTE_TEST T ) T ON T.ROW_NO = M.ROW_NO-1
```

Comment: suppose in place of 1 i replace with 10 the result will change

Comment: here i am using ROW_NUMBER function to generate a record number based on column c1 to identify the starting point. You can use your PK or Unique key instead of c1 to sort/arrange the records. What r the other available columns ...?

Comment: I can change all the available columns (c1,c2,c3)  but it will not effect the required output....